# Rundeck "JSON key /value mapper" LogFilter, variable not available in next step

Tags: json, rundeck

I'm running the Rundeck community edition (3.4.3 2021-08-23).
I have a (winRM) Powershell command step that creates a simple JSON output.

```
@{Hello="World";Simple="Test"} | ConvertTo-Json
```

In this step #1, I have the "JSON jq key/value mapper" added.

[The configuration of the LogFilter is very simple. Just a . (dot) direct passthrough of JSON data. The prefix is set to data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzo5j.png)

The following step #2 is a simple output. Running as (winRM) Powershell command. Just writing the variable output.

```
Write-Output "$result.Simple"
```

Once I run it I can see JSON is produced in step #1 and correctly parsed by the log filter. If I try to access the variable value in step #2 it's empty and produces "No output".

[Both steps 1 and 2 ok. But variable empty. No output from step #2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMZT3.png)

I had success using the Log Filter "Key Value Data" and "Multiline Regex Data Capture". But the "JSON jq key/value mapper" seems to work differently.
I have also tried with upper and lowercase variable names. With "result", "data" and without prefix in the LogFilter configuration. But I can't get around to how to access the data in the variables.

Log Filter: https://resources.rundeck.com/plugins/jq-json-log-filter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `${data.name}` for the command step or `@data.name@` for script step. I made a basic example that gets the value from a JSON file.

Rundeck job definition:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: fb6042da-5e4c-46d2-a2c1-d3a486ce019f
  loglevel: INFO
  name: JSONHelloWorld
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: cat /Users/myuser/Desktop/example.json
      plugins:
        LogFilter:
        - config:
            filter: .
            logData: 'true'
            prefix: result
          type: json-mapper
    - exec: echo ${data.firstName}
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: fb6042da-5e4c-46d2-a2c1-d3a486ce019f
```

[Check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvPJG.jpg) the result.